# Problems with TikZ calculations

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations, coordinates

When can I use functions and do calculations in TikZ?
How do I make this work:

```
\draw (0,0) arc(0:90:sqrt(15)); %not ok
```

why is this working:

```
\draw (0,0) arc(0:asin(1):5); %ok
```

with `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` is this:

```
 \draw (0,0) -- ($ (4,0) + sqrt(7)*(0,1) $);  %ok
```

the only way to do single coordinate calculations? why is this

```
 \draw (0,0) -- ($ (4,sqrt(7)) $);  %not ok
```

not working?

**Minimal example:**

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) arc(0:90:sqrt(15));              %not ok
\draw (0,0) arc(0:asin(1):5);                %ok
\draw (0,0) -- ($ (4,0) + sqrt(7)*(0,1) $);  %ok
\draw (0,0) -- ($ (4,sqrt(7)) $);            %not ok
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please always try to add a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Also post the exact error message you get instead of simply stating "doesn't work". Thanks!

Comment: BTW, you might want to register your account, otherwise you loose access to your old posts after your session expires. Note that you can [now also up-vote](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) answers and other questions.

Comment: @Hans-Peter: Could you try to find a more specific title for this question? Titles with `Problem with` usually aren't very helpful for someone who wants to find out if this question will be helpful or not.

Comment: @doncherry: I will change it, if you suggest something better.

Comment: I'd love to, but I neither use TikZ nor study math. Maybe @MartinScharrer can help?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to wrap the expression into `{ }` to hide the second pair of `( )` from the TeX parser. Without the `{ }` a `(` will be closed by the next `)` even if it belongs to another `(`. This means `arc(0:90:sqrt(15))` will be taken as `arc(0:90:sqrt(15)` without the second `)`. This causes basically two errors, one in the expression because it misses the `)` and another one in the `\draw` path which doesn't know what to do with a single `)`. With the `{ }` it works because any `{` must be closed first with a `}` before the `)` is taken.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) arc(0:90:{sqrt(15)}); %now ok
    \draw (0,0) arc(0:{asin(1)}:5); %ok
    \draw (0,0) -- ($ (4,0) + sqrt(7)*(0,1) $);  %ok
    \draw (0,0) -- ($ (4,{sqrt(7)}) $);  %now ok
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that... The Tikz manual does specify that uou can use curly braces in factors, I should have tried them in coordinates as well. I still don't understand why `asin(x)` in the arc would cause no problems, while `sqrt(x)` does. Can you explain this?

Comment: @whlt3: This all is rooted in the way TeX handles a parameter text, i.e. is a low-level thing and not from TikZ. The `arc` arguments is read by the internal macro `\def\tikz@@@arcto@check@slashand(#1:#2:#3){ ... }` which awaits the three parts between `:`, so a `)` in the second argument can't close the `(` because TeX still looks for the `:` then stores everything up to the next `)` as `#3`. You might want to read *The TeXBook* to learn about such TeX macros.

Comment: Actually, `arc(0:asin(1):5)` works because of the reason stated in my comment above, but `arc(0:{asin(1)}:5)` is much saver. TikZ reads the whole `(...)` first (i.e. `arc(0:asin(1)` with the first form)  and expands it using `\edef`, then passes it to the macro mentioned in my last comment. Using the first form anything after the inner `)` is not expanded!

Comment: Ah, that's awesome :) I'm currently trudging through TeX by Topic, will have a look at the TexBook if I ever get through that.

Comment: See also [TikZ \foreach loop evaluate variable using pgfmath function](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101843/tikz-foreach-loop-evaluate-variable-using-pgfmath-function) for a similar problem..

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** This is incorrect, disregard this.. Well, it's correct up to the point that the coordinates can't have math in them. Disregard it anyway.

It's just how the Tikz calc library is set up. If we have a look at section 13.5 of the [manual](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf)

> The general syntax is the following:
>          ([ options ]$ coordinate computation $).
>        As you can see, the syntax uses the TEX math symbol $ to indicate that a “mathematical computation” is involved. However, the $ has no
>   other eﬀect, in particular, no mathematical text is typeset.
>        The coordinate computation has the following structure:
>       1. It starts with
>                 < factor > * < coordinate > < modiﬁers >
>       2. This is optionally followed by + or - and then another
>                 < factor > * < coordinate > < modiﬁers >
>       3. This is once more followed by + or - and another of the above modiﬁed coordinate; and so on.
>        In the following, the syntax of factors and of the diﬀerent modiﬁers is explained in detail.

The following you will have to read in the manual for yourself. The important thing here is that the math can only occur in the `factor` and the `modifiers`. Not in the coordinate itself, which explains why your second example does not work. The reason the first example doesn't work is explained in the manual as well. It is the same type of restriction in the Tikz grammar.