# How to use trigonometric functions in tikz coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, vector, coordinates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problems with TikZ calculations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31830/problems-with-tikz-calculations)

I am trying to get the following arrows to get lengths defined by a trigonometric function, in this case cos.
This was my attempt, but it does not yield any results:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \y in {1,0.8,...,0}
    \path (1,\y) edge[->] ++(2-cos(\y*pi/2),0)(1,-\y) edge[->] ++(2-cos(\y*pi/2),0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The errors I get are both from tikz/pgf:
"no shape named 2-cos(0 is known."
and "Giving up on this path, did you forget a semicolon?"

Comment: I strongly suspect that this is related to the problem at this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31830/86 where TikZ gets confused by the parentheses.  Take a look at the answers to that and see if they help.  If so, we'll probably close this as a duplicate of that to keep the place tidy.  If not, please edit your question to explain why that doesn't help.

Comment: Indeed this is a duplicate IMHO. You need to mask the inner set of `( )` using `{  }`. Also please always state the exact error you get, "does not yield any results" doesn't tell other people much. Thanks.

Comment: I'm closing this as a duplicate now to avoid repetition on this site. In your case use: `\path (1,\y) edge[->] ++({2-cos(\y*pi/2)},0)
          (1,-\y) edge[->] ++({2-cos(\y*pi/2)},0);` to make it work.