# Calculations and undefined control sequence with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I already produced several figures with TikZ, but I can't see what's wrong with this snippet:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\groundwidth{8.0cm}
        \def\streetwidth{2.0cm}

        \def\gw{0.5*(\groundwidth-\streetwidth)}

        \fill[color=green!75!black] (0, 0) -- (\gw,0) -- (\gw,\gw) -- (0,\gw) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Compiling it with pdftex, it produces the following error message:

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named 0 is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.11 ...ll[color=green!75!black] (0, 0) -- (\gw,0)
                                               -- (\gw,\gw) -- (0,\gw) -...
```

I guess there's something wrong with `\gw`, but I have no idea how to fix I. Do you have any suggestions or a link to the documentation explaining the problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Very related: [Problems with TikZ calculations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31830). Both is basically due to the same syntax limitations, i.e. that `( )` are not matched on a lower level.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution is `\def\gw{{0.5*(\groundwidth-\streetwidth)}}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
        \def\groundwidth{8.0cm}
        \def\streetwidth{2.0cm}
        \def\gw{{0.5*(\groundwidth-\streetwidth)}}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[color=green!75!black] (0, 0) -- (\gw,0) -- (\gw,\gw) -- (0,\gw) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

you can also use

```
 \fill[color=green!75!black] (0, 0) -- ({\gw},0) -- ({\gw},{\gw}) -- (0,{\gw}) -- cycle;
```

instead of

```
  \def\gw{{0.5*(\groundwidth-\streetwidth)}}
```

Comment: This is correct, but lacks an explanation why the error happens and why this solution works.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solution works for me. It was too simple ^^ Is there a special rule when to apply the {}, or do the {} simply force a node in the syntax tree?

Comment: @Sebastian: See my explanation below.

Comment: @Sebastian put the following in your code to see what `\gw` is holding as a variable : `\node at (1.5,1.5) {\gw};`. Then you can appreciate Martin's answer better in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

The reason is that the `\gw` seems to be expanded before the full content of `(  )` is parsed, so:

```
(0, 0) -- (\gw,0)
```

is seen as:

```
(0, 0) -- (0.5*(\groundwidth-\streetwidth),0)
```

Because parenthesis `( )` are not matched like braces `{ }`, the first `)` is taken as the closing one, so TikZ thinks `0.5*(\groundwidth-\streetwidth` is the content. By the parsing rules of TikZ, this doesn't look like a coordinate, because there is no `,` or `:` included. Therefore it is taken as a node name. The syntax is `node name.anchor`, i.e. it thinks `0` is the node name and `5*(\groundwidth-\streetwidth` the anchor name. This leads to the error `No shape named 0 is known` (shape here means node).

The solution is, as Altermundus already pointed out, to enclose the whole `\gw` expression with `{ }`. This forces TeX to look for the closing `}` before it looks further for the `)`, making the inner pair of `( )` work.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Now I understand what causes the error and why the fix works. It seems as if it is worth learning more details of TikZ before I finish my thesis :-)

Comment: @Sebastian: This is actually more about how TeX (i.e. the underlying system of LaTeX) itself parses special input. Instead of only normal arguments, you can use a *parameter text* which contains character usable as separators. E.g. `\def\foo(#1,#2){\bar{#1}{#2}}` will make `\foo` to look for `(` then read everything to the next `,` as argument one and everything else up to the next `)` as argument two. Brace groups however must always be matched beforehand, so you need to wrap content which include `,` or `)` inside `{ }`: `\foo({a*(b+c)},0)`