# TikZ \foreach loop evaluate variable using pgfmath function

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, pgfmath

I have problem with defining a new variable within the `\foreach` loop using the `evaluate` option using a pgfmath function:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \foreach \j [evaluate=\j as \jn using mod(\j,4)] in {5,6} {
      \node[] at (\j,0) {$\jn$};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives me the error:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/foreach/4)'
```

if I replace `mod` with, e.g., `int` or `exp`, (which take only one argument) it works fine.. For instance `exp(\j)` works fine..

Comment: Please see [Problems with TikZ calculations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31830/problems-with-tikz-calculations) for a more complete understanding of this problem..

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think all you need to to do is to add an extra `{}` around the expression as the comma is probably confusing the parser.

```
\foreach  \j [evaluate=\j as \jn using {mod(\j,4)}]  in {5,6}
```

However, I would recommend a slightly different approach and that is to use `pagemathtruncatemacro` (or `\pgfmathsetmacro` if you need real number values) instead:

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \foreach  \j  in {5,6} {
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\jn}{mod(\j,4)}%
       \node[] at (\j,0) {$\jn$};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the nice solution.. I expect that the extra `{` that you added is not the pgfmath array operator? (See chapter 69.1 in the TikZ manual)

Comment: The “official” syntax (i.e. the one in the manual) is `\freach <variable> [<options>] in <list>`. Though the same what is stated in section 15.1 of the PGF manual probably applies here, too.

Comment: @HåkonHægland No, the parser would otherwise split the options at the `,` resulting in two options: `evaluate=\j as \jn using mod(\j` and `4)`. The braces around `mod(\j,4)` will be removed.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Thanks for point that out. Have corrected. You can blame David for this, I tend to not read documentation anymore. :-)

Comment: There is also the (undocumented) syntax `evaluate={\jn=int(mod(\j, 4));}` where multiple evaluations (separated by `;`) can be made. The `int` function does the same as `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`, but is a bit slower as it involves extra parsing.