# pgfmath in graph library giving compilation errors

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath, tikz-graphs

I want to represent a graph where the labels for each node are obtained computing a modulo computation. The first and easy way to do it is as follow :

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def \n {3}
    \graph[clockwise=\n,radius=3cm] {
        \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \xn using {int(mod(\x+1,\n))}] in {0,...,\the\numexpr\n-1} {
            \foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \yn using {int(mod(\y+1,\n))}] in {\x,...,\the\numexpr\n-1} {
                \x / {$a_\x, a_\xn$} --
                \y / {$a_\y, a_\yn$};
            };
        };
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Then I found out about `pgfmathtruncatemacro` and wrote

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def \n {3}
    \graph[clockwise=\n,radius=3cm] {
        \foreach \x in {0,...,\the\numexpr\n-1} {
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xn}{mod(\x+1,\n)}%
            \foreach \y in {\x,...,\the\numexpr\n-1} {
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\yn}{mod(\y+1,\n)}%
                \x / {$a_\x, a_\xn$} --
                \y / {$a_\y, a_\yn$};
            };
        };
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And strangely it gives me these errors :

> ! Undefined control sequence. \pgfmathsetcount ... \pgfmath@onquick #2\pgfmath@ 
>                                                     {\afterassignment \pgfmath... l.16     }
>             ; The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g.,
>   `\hobx'), type`I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox').
>   Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
>
> ! Undefined control sequence. \tikz@lib@graph@handle@node@cont
>   ...kzgraphnodeas 
>                                                     \tikzgraphnodeas@default ... l.16     }
>             ; The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g.,
>   `\hobx'), type`I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox').
>   Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
>
> ! Undefined control sequence. \tikz@lib@graph@typesetter
>   ->\tikzgraphnodetext 
>                                                    l.16     }
>             ; The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g.,
>   `\hobx'), type`I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox').
>   Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
>
> ) ! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 16.  
>                   \fi

And I really can't understand why it wouldn't work.

[EDIT] I wrote my second code based on this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101847/101301). The part where I write `\n - 1` without `\the\numexpr` is not needed when working in Overleaf so it's NOT the problem here. And I don't want to have `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` in the labelling of the node since the answer I linked works perfectly for me too without needing it. My problem is that it looks buggy when using it in the `\graph` environment.

[EDIT 2] Added `\the\numexpr` since it would not compile on every installation of TL and since it was not this that made the program not work.

Comment: The issue is not the `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` but the `\n-1` in the `\foreach` loop, and can be solved e.g. with `\the\numexpr\n-1`. However, even your first example does  not compile.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Good point ! Another solution: add the new (?) `parse=true` option to the `\foreach`...

Comment: @PaulGaborit This is a nice option but I did experience issues, in particular with integers when trying to use it so I do not use it myself.

Comment: The `\graph` macro changes the syntax : you can't use TeX code directly. Here, you must use `[/utils/exec={\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xn}{mod(\x+1,\n)}}]` instead of `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xn}{mod(\x+1,\n)}`...

Comment: @JosephWright It's not just about suppressing error messages since Overleaf actually compiles it (and if I had `[parse=true]` it tells me it doesn't know this command. The image I put was obtained with the first code on Overleaf.

Comment: @JosephWright Here, with the latest TL2018 (updated in april 2019), the first code compiles... And the same code with Overleaf distribution (TL 2018 by default) compiles also.

Comment: I note that the _original_ version of part 1 did not compile cleanly, and that the edit which allows it to work is the same as a suggestion in one of the answers. That is a little odd: could you clarify whether your edit was based on the answer or simply that this is coincidental?

Comment: The thing is I based my edit on the comment made immediately under my question since it didn't change my problem. When I noticed the author of the comment put his comment as an answer I considered it not to be the proper answer since of the two codes, the first one had no problem on my side (in Overleaf) when the second one wouldn't be compiled. I hope I answered your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\graph` macro changes the syntax: you can't use TeX code directly. You can use the `/utils/exec` key to execute some arbitrary TeX code.

Here is a solution with the final version of TeXLive 2018 (used by Overleaf, cf. [TeX Live upgrade Sep.2019](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/tex-live-upgrade-september-2019)):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def \n {3}
    \graph[clockwise=\n,radius=3cm] {
        \foreach \x in {0,...,\n-1} {
            [/utils/exec={\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xn}{mod(\x+1,\n)}}]%
            \foreach \y in {\x,...,\n-1} {
                [/utils/exec={\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\yn}{mod(\y+1,\n)}}]%
                \x / {$a_\x, a_\xn$} --
                \y / {$a_\y, a_\yn$};
            };
        };
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And, here is a solution with TeXLive 2019:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\n{3}
  \graph[clockwise=\n,radius=3cm] {
    \foreach[parse=true] \x in {0,...,\n-1} {
      [/utils/exec={\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xn}{mod(\x+1,\n)}}]
      \foreach[parse=true] \y in {\x,...,\n-1} {
        [/utils/exec={\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\yn}{mod(\y+1,\n)}}]
        \x / {$a_\x, a_\xn$} --
        \y / {$a_\y, a_\yn$};
      }
    }
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is a solution with TeXLive 2019 using `\pgfmathsetmacro` to compute `\xmax` (without the `parse` option that still does not work very well):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\n{3}
  \graph[clockwise=\n,radius=3cm] {
    [/utils/exec={\pgfmathsetmacro\xmax{int(\n-1)}}]
    \foreach \x in {0,...,\xmax} {
      [/utils/exec={\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xn}{mod(\x+1,\n)}}]
      \foreach \y in {\x,...,\xmax} {
        [/utils/exec={\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\yn}{mod(\y+1,\n)}}]
        \x / {$a_\x, a_\xn$} --
        \y / {$a_\y, a_\yn$};
      }
    }
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I see. Overleaf does compile this. +1.  (My problem with parse is that some things do not work, e.g. ` \foreach[parse=true] \x in {0,...,{int(\n-1)}}` gives an error.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I see the same problem. The `parse` option is probably not fully developed.

Comment: Yes. There are also some hidden gems like a function `dim` that returns the length of an array but does not always work. There are problems when the last item of the list is "non-atomic". (I do not know whether `parse` has been a hidden gem for a while, but I am pretty positive that it only made it to the manual very recently.)

Comment: Funny how the tone changes when talking to someone with a big score and a simple user asking a question. Thanks for your answer, I didn't know Overleaf was hiding error messages and I tried it on my distro this morning noticing the error messages. 
@Schrödinger'scat That's how you answer to someone. You may tell them they have some errors in their code asserting the fact that on their side the code may have compiled and thus answering their question. Or at least don't post a comment as an answer when it doesn't answer the question asked. Thanks for the remark about `\n - 1` though.

Comment: @Lhooq Well, your code did and does *not* compile, and I pointed that out and fixed it. All you did was to charge into me and to downvote me. And now this remark. Well, you have presumably a way of interpreting this in your own way, and I have my way of rating this behavior. My tone did not change, I am just allergic to wrong statements and undeserved downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

This is a compilable version of your first example. I do not see any benefit in using `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` since you'd also have to wrap it into `\pgfextra` and so on if you want to use it in a path.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def \n {3}
    \graph[clockwise=\n,radius=3cm] {
        \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \xn using {int(mod(\x+1,\n))}] in
        {0,...,\the\numexpr\n-1} {
            \foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \yn using {int(mod(\y+1,\n))}] in
            {\x,...,\the\numexpr\n-1} {
                \x / {$a_\x, a_\xn$} --
                \y / {$a_\y, a_\yn$}
            }
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And here is a version where `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` gets used. Luckily in this application the result is not needed for the path but only for typesetting. So you can add `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` just to the stuff you want to typeset.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def \n {3}
    \graph[clockwise=\n,radius=3cm] {
        \foreach \x  in {0,...,\the\numexpr\n-1} {
            \foreach \y in {\x,...,\the\numexpr\n-1} {               
                \x / {$\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xn}{int(mod(\x+1,\n))}a_\x, a_\xn$} --
                \y / {$\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\yn}{int(mod(\y+1,\n))}a_\y, a_\yn$}
            }
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]