# Drawing nodes by polar coordinates with translation

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have plotted 12 nodes in a circle with radius 2 and center (0,0) (I suppose). Now I want to plot it once more in the same figure but with centre (2,0), how could this be achieved? Many thanks for any help!

My current code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \a in {1,...,12}
    {
        \node[vertex] (u\a) at ({\a*30}:2){};
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption*{\footnotesize{Figure 3}}
\end{figure}
```

It looks like:

[image]

I have tried like `({\a*30}:2)+(2,0)` but doesn't work.

Comment: Try this: `\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm] ... code as before ... \end{scope}`.

Comment: @Salomo What do you mean? You can draw edges the same way you did the nodes in both foreach statements.

Comment: Not tested: `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` and then `($ ({\a*30}:2) + (2,0) $)`. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31830/problems-with-tikz-calculations

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen Thanks!!! That is a perfect solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

si j'ai bien compris la question, une solution!

if I understand the question, a solution

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \aa in{0,5}{
    \begin{scope}[xshift=\aa cm]
    \foreach \a in {1,...,12}
    {
        \node[circle,draw] (u\a) at ({\a*30}:2){};
    }
    \end{scope}
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption*{\footnotesize{Figure 3}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]