# Tikz error when using trigonometric functions

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I use the following code:

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (.2*tan(10) and .4*tan(10));
\end{tikzpicture}
```

... then I get an error message. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is the error message?  What does a full document which we can compile to replicate the error message look like?

Comment: Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?. \draw (0,0) circle (.2*tan(10))
It is the error message and the code above itself is the full document for this question.

Comment: the code in the question is not complete - no `\documentclass`, `\usepackage`s, `\begin{document}` or `\end{document}` so if I compile your code I will not replicate your error but a `missing \documentclass` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work if we put the computed radii in brackets.

### Some reference per request :

[Martin Scharrer explains it here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31833/116936) better than I can.

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) circle ({.2*tan(10)} and {.4*tan(10)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Cheers,

Comment: Thank you so much! Can I ask an another question please? I wonder how the method you suggested works in principle.

Comment: @eigenvalue : see the edit for some reference on the fix. It is a common issue.