# Tikz error: Missing number, treated as zero

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am having an issue with Tikz. Here is the code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]

% Variables
\def\mu{0.1}
\def\R{10}

%Celestial bodies
\draw [thick, fill=yellow] (0,0) circle (1);
\draw [thick, fill=cyan] (\R,0) circle (0.25);

% Lagrangian points
\node at (\R*{1-{\mu/3}^{1/3}},0) {\color{orange}{\huge$\bullet$}}; %L1
\node at (\R*{1+{\mu/3}^{1/3}},0) {\color{orange}{\huge$\bullet$}}; %L2
\node at (-\R*{1+5/12*\mu},0) {\color{orange}{\huge$\bullet$}}; %L3
\node at (\R*{1/2*{1-2*\mu}},\R*sqrt(3)/2) {\color{orange}{\huge$\bullet$}}; %L4
\node at (\R*{1/2*{1-2*\mu}},-\R*sqrt(3)/2) {\color{orange}{\huge$\bullet$}}; %L5


\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here is the error I get:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
{
l.87 \node at (\R*{1-{\mu/3}^{1/3}},0)
{\color{orange}{\huge$\bullet$}}; %L1
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
```

I see this is a common error with Tikz but I can't find out why it doesn't work. It is propably a silly mistake, can someone tell me what's wrong ?

Comment: Off topic: I don’t think that it is a good idea to use `\def` to define macros that are already existing.

Comment: You mean I can simply put mu=0.1 and R=10 ? Or do you mean I have to use another method ?

Comment: No, you cannot. I mean that you should use other macro names, since `\mu` is already defined representing µ. If you overwrite it, you cannot use it for its original purpose any more.

Comment: Ah ok I understand, I will change that then. Thank you !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There were three problems:

1. If you are doing a calculation in a coordinate you must enclose it<sup><sup><sub>1</sub></sup></sup> with braces: `({\R*sqrt(3)},0)`
2. Inside an operation, you group with parentheses, not braces.

Fixed code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]

% Variables
\newcommand{\muu}{0.1}
\newcommand{\R}{10}

%Celestial bodies
\draw [thick, fill=yellow] (0,0) circle (1);
\draw [thick, fill=cyan] (\R,0) circle (0.25);

\node at ({\R*(1-(\muu/3)^(1/3))},0) {\color{orange}{\huge$\bullet$}}; %L1
\node at ({\R*(1+(\muu/3)^(1/3))},0) {\color{orange}{\huge$\bullet$}}; %L2
\node at ({-\R*(1+5/12*\muu)},0) {\color{orange}{\huge$\bullet$}}; %L3
\node at ({\R*(1/2*(1-2*\muu))},{\R*sqrt(3)/2}) {\color{orange}{\huge$\bullet$}}; %L4
\node at ({\R*(1/2*(1-2*\muu))},{-\R*sqrt(3)/2}) {\color{orange}{\huge$\bullet$}}; %L5

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The third problem:

As Jasper said, avoid using `\def`, unless you are absolutely sure of what you're doing. The `\mu` you are defining already exists (the greek letter μ).

If you use `\newcommand` instead, LaTeX will tell you that you are redefining an existing macro.

---

<sup><sup><sub>1</sub></sup></sup> That's not the whole story. When Ti*k*Z finds a `(` it understands that it's reading a coordinate. It also expects that the next `)` will end the coordinate.

So when Ti*k*Z finds `(\R*sqrt(3),0)`, it understands `\R*sqrt(3` as the coordinate, which is bad, and still, it gets a `,0)` after, which is worse. But when you group the expression inside braces, everything inside the `{...}` will be treated as a single token, which will be passed to the math interpreter to do its job.

So whenever you have expressions *with parentheses*, you have to hide them inside `{...}`. Although its no harm to enclose an expression without parentheses too.

Thanks to @hpekristiansen for pointing that out!

Comment: Awesome thank you ! So I juste have to add {...} around the math expression ? What did you edit out \usetikzlibrary{calc} ?

Comment: @LoïcPoncin You have to add the `{...}` around the math expression and group the operations with `(...)` (you was grouping with `{...}`). I included the `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` at first, but then I realised that it is not necessary for this example, so I removed it.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, I have to mention that you are a little bit lucky... Any greek character that defined by `\namecommand` has an uppercase defined by `\Namecommand`... In this case uppercase `\mu` happens to be same as latin `M` and so is not defined as `\Mu`...

Comment: @koleygr That's exactly why I used `\Mu` and not `\muu` ;) Thanks!

Comment: For safety I would use `\MU` or `\muu` insrtead... (Someone could use a command to upercase greek letters in math mode...) Any way... (+1)

Comment: @koleygr Hmmm... Good point :)

Comment: "you must enclose it with braces" is not entirely true the real explanation can be read here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31833/8650

Comment: @hpekristiansen Oooh, now I get it. Thanks!