Multiple ways to sketch the slope field using Latex
Hi there to all latex experts, I am a latex learner from Hong Kong, my first latex experience started as an undergraduate student, now after a few years of graduation, I am back at it. This is my first time to ask a question on this website.
Today, I am trying to sketch a slope field using latex. I know that there are many ways to do it, I am using one of them
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\title{$O_1-D_1-E_1$}
\author{}
\date{}
\usepackage{pgfplots} %%%%% Use for every diagram plots :D
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}

\pgfplotsset{OhDE/.style={
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$},
    axis equal image,
    view={0}{90},
    samples=21,
    cycle list={
        blue,
        quiver={
            u={1/\length}, v={f(x)/\length},
                scale arrows=0.3,
                every arrow/.append style={},
            }\\
        [red, samples=60, smooth, thick, no markers, domain=-5:5]\\
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\def\length{sqrt(1+(x^2-y)^2)}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x, \y)=(\x)^2-\y;}]
    \begin{axis}[OhDE,
    width=0.5\textwidth,
    xmin=-5, xmax=5,
    ymin=-5, ymax=5,
    domain=-5:5, y domain=-5:5,
    xtick={-5,-4,...,5}, ytick={-5,-4,...,5}
    ]
    \addplot3 (x,y,0);
    \addplot {x^2-2*x+2}; %Error detection by latex
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Unfortunately, all I get is a lovely error message:

Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the supplied plot command is unknown or unsupported by pgfplots! Ignoring it..

Error description is below:
See the pgfplots package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.49     \addplot {
                   x^2-2*x+2};
This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.

Can anyone tell me how can I fix that so I can have a nice slope field on the output that works for every 1st order ODE problem.
As I said, if I succeed, then I move on to use other method to sketch the slope field.
Latex is a fun thing to try. :D
written by Hector

\addplot3 (x,y,0); doesn't seem to match any of the addplot3 syntax options shown in the pgfplots manual, where did you see that and what did you expect it to do?

Your  program often causes my TeXworks to crash after changes.
I think the syntax you use in cycle list={} is not allowed (no idea where you got it from).
Maybe someone can solve it for you, otherwise my tip would be: start with something simple, describe (with pictures!) what it should be in the end; and then you might be able to get to grips with it.

Welcome to TeX.SX!

Hi everyone, I was off-site yesterday because I want to take a break from it. Speaking of the commands and codes used in my programme, I used this link as a reference, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139064/how-to-draw-slope-fields-with-all-the-possible-solution-curves-in-latex

At this point, I talk to myself that how can I do that without changing the progress that I made so far, this link has everything I need, (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588397/slope-field-for-differential-equation-with-cube-root-missing-number-treated-a), they both have the command \addplot (x,y,0) and cycle list={}.

I expect that \addplot (x,y,0) gives the nice slope field diagram with a uniform length of lines. I hope that this answer your question, @DavidCarlisle.

and @cis, again it is my first time to write a comment in this website. I thought I can send this long message in one go, but unlucky, I have to split it into pieces.

@HectorLai you knew the link. Does my answer in that link answer your question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/471720/140722

Hi @BlackMild, I think I partially answer that question but not fully as I am trying to use your method (the third method (leaving my second method aside)) before then but I end up with some unavoidable mistakes, so the latex is struggling to produce the output. Maybe I can upload this question in a separate page so that it can keep things clean and clear.

As I understand, you want two plots
\addplot3[%
  blue,
  quiver={
     u={1/\length}, v={f(x,y)/\length},
     scale arrows=0.3,
     every arrow/.append style={},
  }
](x,y,0);

(where I corrected f(x) by f(x,y) as f is a two dimensional function) and
\addplot[red, samples=60, smooth, thick, no markers, domain=-5:5]{x^2-2*x+2};

It seems simpler to me to write these as it, but if you want to use cycle list you must remove the square brackets
cycle list={
  blue,
  quiver={
    u={1/\length}, v={f(x,y)/\length},
    scale arrows=0.3,
    every arrow/.append style={},
  }\\
  red, samples=60, smooth, thick, no markers, domain=-5:5\\
}

Example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\pgfplotsset{%
  OhDE/.style={%
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$},
    axis equal image,
    view={0}{90},
    samples=21,
    cycle list={
      blue,
      quiver={
        u={1/\length}, v={f(x,y)/\length},
        scale arrows=0.3,
        every arrow/.append style={},
      }\\
      red, samples=60, smooth, thick, no markers, domain=-5:5\\
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}

\def\length{sqrt(1+(x^2-y)^2)}

\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x, \y)=(\x)^2-\y;}]
  \begin{axis}[%
      OhDE,
      width=0.5\textwidth,
      xmin=-5, xmax=5,
      ymin=-5, ymax=5,
      domain=-5:5, y domain=-5:5,
      xtick={-5,-4,...,5}, ytick={-5,-4,...,5}
    ]
    \addplot3 (x,y,0);
    \addplot {x^2-2*x+2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Nice ... but does it make sense contentwise?

@MS-SPO I only debugged the code. You should ask the OP.

I know, it's intended to be a question to the OP

That worked, thanks. But @jlab I have a question, how can you post this diagram in a comment section, did you do screenshot on your computer or something else?

@HectorLai You can post images in answers and questions from the toolbar. This works also with screenshots. See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2781/316068 if needed. You can't post images in comments, but you can post a link to it, if you uploaded it somewhere.
