# Why do we need extra braces in ellipse when using a constant?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

What is the best way to declare a constant to be used within TikZ? I am using `\pgfmathsetmacro` because I have seen others do it on this site. A constant should be a simple thing, so I am bit confused why it should be necessary to use a low level(pgf) command for this!?
When using the ellipse command I have a strange problem where I need to wrap the constant in an extra set of `{}` when used like this:

`\draw (6,6) ellipse (\r and 1);`.

Error:

> ! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator 'a' or 'an' (in '1and
>   1').

Why is that?

Related: [Problems with TikZ calculations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31830/problems-with-tikz-calculations)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{1}
  \draw (0,0) ellipse (1 cm and 1 cm);    %ok
  \draw (1,1) ellipse (1 and 1);          %ok
  \draw (2,2) ellipse (1 cm and \r cm);   %ok
  \draw (3,3) ellipse (1 and \r);         %ok
  \draw (4,4) ellipse (\r cm and 1 cm);   %ok
  \draw (5,5) ellipse ({\r} and 1);       %ok
  \draw (6,6) ellipse (\r and 1);         %not ok
  \draw (7,7) ellipse (\r{} and 1);       %ok
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** From @marmot's comment and experiment I have found, that `\constant{}` also works as in `\draw (7,7) ellipse (\r{} and 1);`... but what is the correct way to declare and use a constant - I can not find it in the TikZ manual. Should I always use `\constant{}`, or maybe only when problems arise?

Comment: `\r and` expands to  `1and` which the parser cannot make sense of.

Comment: @marmot: Yes - but who ate the space? What is correct syntax? I do not suppose it is `\r{}` !? Like in `\newcommand{\abc}{\emph{abc}}` `\abc{}`.

Comment: Isn't that just the usual behavior of TeX? `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello Car\LaTeX how's your day?
\end{document}`

Comment: @marmot: Yes - I try to always use `\LaTeX{}` (as I do not use xspace). -but does `\pgfmathsetmacro` work the same way as commands?

Comment: It has nothing to do specifically with `\pgfmathsetmacro` but with the fact that `\r` is a macro and trailing spaces get eaten up, just like spaces after `\LaTeX` do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's from the old parts of the code and this is something that should have been done via keys. In `tikz.code.tex` you can find this

```
\def\tikz@@@circle(#1){%
  {%
    \pgftransformshift{\tikz@last@position}%
    \pgfutil@in@{ and }{#1}% <==== This is the part that it looks for a pattern
    \ifpgfutil@in@%
      \tikz@@ellipseB(#1)%
    \else%
      \tikz@do@circle{#1}{#1}%
    \fi%
  }%
  \tikz@scan@next@command%
}
```

Since there is whitespace around the `and` you need to have whitespace around it.

This usage is deprecated by the developers and they recommend `ellipse [x radius=<>, y radius=<>]` syntax.

This is both mentioned in the manual and also in the source code comments

```
% Syntax for circles:
% circle [options] % where options should set, at least, radius
% circle (radius) % deprecated
%
% Syntax for ellipses:
% ellipse [options] % identical to circle.
% ellipse (x-radius and y-radius) % deprecated
%
% radii can be dimensionless, then they are in the xy-system
```

For example in the `positioning` syntax, you don't have this problem

```
%\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) {a};
\node[above=1of a] {b};% 1cmof a also works
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: +1 How do you know that? :)