# How to draw any polygram using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've been trying to create a command to generalize this but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Maybe it's more complex than I thought. How should I do it? Please include descriptions to steps because I don't know too much about latex and tikz. Also explain what I'm doing wrong please.

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\polygram}[4]{%radius, number of total points, connect points skipping this number of points, draw options
\draw[#4] ({360/#2}:#1) %draw at starting point
\foreach \x in {1, ..., #2} %cycle through other points, drawing to the next, skipping #3 points
{ -- ({360/(\x+#3)}:#1)} -- cycle;
}

\tikz \polygram{2}{5}{2}{blue};

\end{document}
```

More info: [Polygram (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygram_(geometry))

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: I do not have time to answer now - part/all of your problem is related to: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31830/problems-with-tikz-calculations

Comment: Don't have `--` without a coordinate after it, move it outside the loop. Besides @hpekristiansen's link, the coordinate in the loop has a `)` too many. It should be at least `({360/(\x+#3)}:#1)`.

Comment: Ok, I made all the edits suggested, at least I'm getting a drawing now, but it's not the figure I want

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think, what you're after is something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\polygram}[4][]{
    % options, radius, # of total points, # of skipping points
    \draw[#1] (0:#2) 
    \foreach \x in {1,...,#3} {
        -- ({360/#3*(\x-1)*#4}:#2) 
    } -- cycle
}

\tikz \polygram[blue]{2}{5}{2};

\end{document}
```

[image]

As comparison, `\tikz \polygram[blue]{2}{10}{3};` yields:

[image]

---

Note that 0 degees is to the right. In order to draw the diagram with its starting point upwards, you need to turn everything by 90 degrees counterclockwise:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\polygram}[4][]{
    % options, radius, # of total points, # of skipping points
    \draw[#1] (90:#2) 
    \foreach \x in {1,...,#3} {
        -- ({360/#3*(\x-1)*#4+90}:#2) 
    } -- cycle
}

\tikz \polygram[blue]{2}{5}{2};

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

And because I recently got to like `pic`s so much, a solution using a `pic`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    pics/polygram/.style={
        code={
            \tikzset{polygram/.cd, #1}
            \draw[pic actions] (90:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/polygram/radius}}) 
                \foreach \x in {1,...,{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/polygram/total points}}} {
                    -- ({ 360 /
                          \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/polygram/total points} *
                          (\x - 1) * 
                          \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/polygram/skipping points} + 
                          90 } : 
                        {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/polygram/radius}}) 
                } -- cycle;    
        }
    },
    polygram/.cd,
    radius/.initial=1,
    total points/.initial=5,
    skipping points/.initial=2,
}

\tikz \pic[blue] {polygram={radius=2}};

\tikz \pic[red, thick] {polygram={total points=7}};

\tikz \pic[cyan, dashed] {polygram={radius=2, total points=7, skipping points=3}};

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

This version also works with *p* (total number of points) and *q* (number of points skipped) that are evenly divisible:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    pics/polygram/.style={
        code={
            \tikzset{polygram/.cd, #1}
            \pgfmathparse{
                mod(
                    \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/polygram/total points} ,
                    \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/polygram/skipping points} 
                ) == 0 ? \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/polygram/skipping points} : 1
            }
            \foreach \r in {0,...,\pgfmathresult} {
                \begin{scope}[rotate={360/\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/polygram/total points}*\r}]
                    \draw[pic actions] (90:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/polygram/radius}}) 
                        \foreach \x in {1,...,{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/polygram/total points}}} {
                            -- ({ 360 /
                                  \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/polygram/total points} *
                                  (\x - 1) * 
                                  \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/polygram/skipping points} + 
                                  90 } : 
                                {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/polygram/radius}}) 
                        } -- cycle;
                \end{scope}
            }
        }
    },
    polygram/.cd,
    radius/.initial=1,
    total points/.initial=5,
    skipping points/.initial=2,
}

\tikz \pic[blue] {polygram={total points=12, skipping points=4}};

\tikz \pic[blue] {polygram={total points=6, skipping points=2}};

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

An adjustment to be able to style the different layers individually and to add stylable dots at the tips:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    pics/polygram/.style={
        code={
            \tikzset{polygram/.cd, #1}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\polygramlayers}{
                mod(
                    \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/polygram/total points} ,
                    \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/polygram/skipping points} 
                ) == 0 ? \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/polygram/skipping points} : 1
            }
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\polygramnodesperlayer}{
                int(
                    \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/polygram/total points} / 
                    \polygramlayers 
                )
            }
            \foreach \r in {1,...,\polygramlayers} {
                \tikzset{polygram layer \r/.initial={}}
                \begin{scope}[
                    rotate={360/\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/polygram/total points}*\r}, 
                    pic actions,
                    polygram layer \r
                ]
                    \draw (90:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/polygram/radius}}) 
                            node[polygram dot] {}   
                        \foreach \x in {1,...,\polygramnodesperlayer} {
                            -- ({ 360 /
                                  \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/polygram/total points} *
                                  (\x - 1) * 
                                  \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/polygram/skipping points} + 
                                  90 } : 
                                {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/polygram/radius}}) 
                                    node[polygram dot] {}
                        } -- cycle;
                \end{scope}
            }
        }
    },
    polygram dot/.style={circle, fill, inner sep=1pt},
    polygram/.cd,
    radius/.initial=1,
    total points/.initial=5,
    skipping points/.initial=2,
}

\tikz 
    \pic[blue, 
        polygram dot/.append style={draw=black},
        polygram layer 1/.style={magenta, thick, polygram dot/.append style={fill=orange}}, 
        polygram layer 2/.style={red}
    ] 
    {polygram={total points=12, skipping points=4}};

\tikz 
    \pic[blue] {polygram={total points=5, skipping points=3}};

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

A non-`pic` version of the last variant would be:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    polygram dot/.style={circle, fill, inner sep=1pt}
}

\newcommand{\polygram}[4][]{
    % options, radius, # of total points, # of skipping points
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\polygramlayers}{
        mod(#3,#4) == 0 ? #4 : 1
    }
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\polygramnodesperlayer}{
        int(#3/\polygramlayers)
    }
    \node at (0,0) {\polygramlayers};
    \foreach \r in {0,...,\polygramlayers} {
        \tikzset{polygram layer \r/.initial={}}
        \begin{scope}[rotate={360/#3 * \r}, #1, polygram layer \r]
            \draw (90:{#2}) node[polygram dot] {}   
                \foreach \x in {1,...,\polygramnodesperlayer} {
                    -- ({360/#3 * (\x - 1) * #4 + 90}:{#2}) node[polygram dot] {}
                } -- cycle;
        \end{scope}
    }
}

\tikz \polygram[blue]{1}{5}{2};

\tikz \polygram[blue, polygram layer 1/.style={red}]{1}{12}{4};

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted! Do you know how to get the pentagram facing up, it's like slightly tilted.

Comment: Rotate it by 90 degrees. 0 (zero) is on the right side, so if you turn everything by 90 degrees (counterclockwise), the drawings will start at the top.

Comment: Sorry fot the strange alignment of the calculation for the point in the pic. I didn't want to make the lines in the code too long ...

Comment: I'll add that while this is what I needed, this only works for irrational ratio between number of points (p) and number of skipped points (q). If someone wants to improve this it will need to check if the mentioned ratio is an integer, and if true then make two figures with p/q number of points and 1 skipped point, and rotate one of them the value of the angle.

Comment: @Vampi See my edit.

Comment: since you seem to keep working on this, do you have this as a command instead of pics? Just to understand everything better, as I'm still a noob

Comment: @Vampi Added, and fixed some erros in the other variants.

Answer (score 10):

This defines one key `Schlaefli star = p/q` (where *p* and *q* are integers that do *not* share any factors). This corresponds to the section [Generalized regular polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygram_(geometry)#Generalized_regular_polygons) on your linked Wikipedia page.

This key is also used internally by `Schlaefli comp = n/m` which follows the section [Regular compound polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygram_(geometry)#Regular_compound_polygons). Again, *n* and *m* must be integers.
Choosing *n* and *m* so that they fulfill the conditions of *p* and *q* will lead to a GCD of 1 and a “normal” star will be drawn, just as an edge.

---

Both will only work for integers. Technically, not all the `\pgfinteval`s are necessary (they carry out integer arithmetics via eTeX' primitives) but they together with `.expanded` lower the need to evaluate the same expression multiple times.

If you need to change the radius, use [`scale`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-transformations#tikz/scale) or change the [`x` and `y` value](https://tikz.dev/tikz-transformations#sec-25.2) of the *xyz* coordinate system. The transformation [`rotate`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-transformations#tikz/rotate) can be used to rotate the whole polygram.

---

I've chose not to define a command that issues `\draw` itself but to implement this as a key. This means, the control is with you with the actual `\draw`. You can also use `\fill` or other options without an extra interface.

The compound polygons are implemented via an `edge` which means they can each have a different color or other options. (You could draw one, fill the other and pattern the third …) This is controlled via the `Schlaefli edge` key that takes two arguments, the current edge and the total number of edges. Though, they go from 0 to *k*−1 instead of 1 to *k*.

Similar, the `Schlaefli dot` key gets the number of the corner (counting from 0) forwarded which can be used as `#1`.

So with something like

```
\tikz[
  scale=2,
  ultra thick,
  Schlaefli edge/.style 2 args={
    draw=c#1,
    Schlaefli dot/.append style={thick, minimum size=2mm, fill=c#1, draw=c##1}},
  color let/.code args={#1=#2}{\colorlet{c#1}{#2}},
  color let/.list={
    0=red, 1=orange, 2=yellow, 3=green, 4=blue, 5=violet, 6=magenta}
] \path[Schlaefli comp=28/7];
```

you can produce this, uh, *beautiful* picture:

[image]

---

I'm using the `full arc` key and the `R` post-fix operator of the `ext.misc` library of my [`tikz-ext` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext) since it allows me to not have to calculate the angular steps myself. Simply giving the options `full arc = 5` means that `1R` equals 72°, `2R` equals 144° and so one. This is of course not necessary and in fact, in `Schlaefli comp` I've used the explicit version to rotate each of the *k* polygons.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.misc}
\tikzset{
  Schlaefli dot/.style={
    shape=circle, inner sep=+0pt, fill, minimum size=+2.5pt, node contents=},
  Schlaefli star/.style args={#1/#2}{
    full arc={#1},
    insert path={
      (0R:1 and 1) node[Schlaefli dot=0]
        foreach \CORNER in {1,...,\pgfinteval{#1-1}}{
        -- ({\CORNER*(#2)*1R}:1 and 1) node[Schlaefli dot/.expanded=\CORNER]}
        -- cycle}},
  Schlaefli comp/.style args={#1/#2}{
    /utils/exec=\pgfmathgcd{#1}{#2}\let\tikzSchlaefliGCD\pgfmathresult,
    insert path={
     foreach[expand list] \POLY in {0, ..., \pgfinteval{\tikzSchlaefliGCD-1}}{
       (0,0) edge[
         Schlaefli edge/.try/.expanded={\POLY}{\pgfinteval{\tikzSchlaefliGCD-1}},
         to path/.expanded={[rotate=\pgfinteval{360/(#1)*\POLY},
           Schlaefli star=\pgfinteval{(#1)/\tikzSchlaefliGCD}/%
                          \pgfinteval{(#2)/\tikzSchlaefliGCD}]}]()}}}}
\begin{document}
\tikz[
  thick, line join=round,
  Schlaefli edge/.style 2 args={
    color/.pgfmath wrap={red!##1!orange}{#1/#2*100}},
  row sep=1mm, column sep=1mm]
\matrix{
  \draw[Schlaefli star= 5/2];
& \draw[Schlaefli star= 7/2];
& \draw[Schlaefli star= 7/3];
& \draw[Schlaefli star= 8/3]; \\
% https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptagram#/media/File:Heptagrams.svg
  \tikzset{Schlaefli dot/.append style=coordinate, rotate=90}
  \draw[red,   Schlaefli star=7/1];
  \draw[blue,  Schlaefli star=7/2];
  \draw[green, Schlaefli star=7/3];
& \draw[Schlaefli star= 9/2];
& \draw[Schlaefli star= 9/4];
& \draw[Schlaefli star=10/3]; \\
  \path[Schlaefli comp= 6/2];
& \path[Schlaefli comp= 9/3];
& \path[Schlaefli comp=12/4];
& \path[Schlaefli comp= 8/2]; \\
  \path[Schlaefli comp=12/3];
& \path[Schlaefli comp=10/2];
& \path[Schlaefli comp=10/4];
& \path[
    c0/.style=red, c1/.style=green, c2/.style=orange,
    c3/.style=blue, c4/.style=yellow!50!black,
    Schlaefli edge/.append style=c##1,
    Schlaefli dot/.append style=black,
    Schlaefli comp=15/6];
\\};

\tikz[
  scale=2,
  ultra thick,
  Schlaefli edge/.style 2 args={
    draw=c#1,
    Schlaefli dot/.append style={thick, minimum size=2mm, fill=c#1, draw=c##1},
  },
  color let/.code args={#1=#2}{\colorlet{c#1}{#2}},
  color let/.list={
    0=red, 1=orange, 2=yellow, 3=green, 4=blue, 5=violet, 6=magenta}
] \path[Schlaefli comp=28/7];

\begin{tikzpicture}[Schlaefli dot/.append style=coordinate, rotate=90]
  \fill[red,   Schlaefli star=7/1];
  \fill[blue,  Schlaefli star=7/2];
  \fill[green, Schlaefli star=7/3];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This creates a polygram with `\nsides` sides.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}

\def\nsides{5}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={r=2;c=360/\nsides;}]
        \foreach \i in {1,...,\nsides}{
            \draw[blue](\i*c:r)--(\i*c+2*c:r);
            \fill[red](\i*c:r)circle(.03);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Result of code is not consistent. Two of edges overlap circles.